# Checkstyle - How to exclude any file, but the ones ending with 'Impl.java', with a regex?

Tags: regex, checkstyle

I have been thinking some time about this problem.

I have a huge Maven multi module project and using build-tools I share a custom set of rules for all modules (no problem around here).

The problem comes when I want to apply one rule to just one set of files in just one of the modules. By using checkstyle suppressions file I can easyly exclude all files that I don't want the rule to apply, but it has its limitations. Lets put this into an example:

Files:

```
a/b/c/d/FileImpl.java
a/b/c/d/File.java
a/b/c/d/e/FileImpl.java
a/b/c/FileImpl.java
...
```

What regex would you write that assures you that all files (including future files that may be introduced) get excluded but just the ones that end with Impl.java under package a.b.c.d? **in terms of regex, it has to be a regex that matches anything but the file ending I want.**

It would be easyer if I could just set an "includes" referring only to the set of files to apply the rule to, but as far as I know that's not possible. It has to be using suppressions, so that it suppresses all files but the ones I want.

I have tried using capturing groups, lookahead and lookbehind but had no success at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include your attempted solutions...which can help others understand what you're driving at.

Comment: Hi Adi, What I'm trying is to make a generic regex that matches everything but one chain ending with d/FileImpl.java so that Checkstyle suppressions excludes all files but the one that doesn't match the regex. Something like: .+(?!d/FileImpl.java$)

Comment: @xOUe post your solution as an answer (and probably accept it), don't edit it into your question. posting answers to your own questions is perfectly valid here!

Comment: there is a limitation on newbies, cannot answer my own question before 8h... otherwise I would have done it, Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right solution to the not so clear question, hope it helps anyone interested.

http://fiddle.re/9wvfg

Regex Goal --> match any chain but the ones that match the internal regex.

Regex --> `^((?!d/\w+Impl\.java).)*$`

Using negative lookahead and the template: `^((?!regexp).)*$`

Thanks for the support!!

Answer (score 0):

> *What regex would you write that assures you that all files (including future files that may be introduced) get excluded but just the ones that end with Impl.java under package a.b.c.d?*

Try this regex:

```
a/b/c/d/.+Impl\.java$
```

#### Demo

http://fiddle.re/rpqgg

Comment: Hi Alex, It doesn't work as I expect... '?' makes optional the preceeding token (.+ in this case)

Comment: I didn't explain myself clearly enough, what I expect from the regex is that it matches any path file but a/b/c/d/FileImpl.java so that it's the only file that gets the checkstyle rule applied

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to keep playing with that tool