# Checkstyle to match and allow legal annotation parameter values

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have an annotation that can have value of a parameter as the string representation of the array of string (e.g. "[\"Value1\", \"Value2\"]"). So basically the value of the annotation is a string. E.g.

```
@MyAnn(value = "[\"V1\"]")
```

Valid set of the strings can only be either:

1. `value = "[\"V1\", \"V2\", \"\"]"`
2. `value = "[ ]"`
3. `value = "[]"`
4. `value = ""`

A legal regex that matches these strings is:

```
value = (?:\"\[\s*(\\\".*\")*\s*\]\"|\"\"|\"\[\s*\]\")
```

I'd like to have a checkstyle such that if when someone is using `@MyAnn` then the value must be one of the 4. Anything else should be reported as the violation.

The problem I am having is how to specify the regex for the invalid values (mine is for valid values). Because the [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#Content) needs me to specify the regex for the illegal values.

What would be the way to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Surround your regex with the `?!` negative lookahead assertion:

```
^((?!(?:\"\[\s*(\\\".*\")*\s*\]\"|\"\"|\"\[\s*\]\")).)*$
```

See [Checkstyle - How to exclude any file, but the ones ending with 'Impl.java', with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21851615/62162)